# INSERT INTO statement with variable in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, variables, insert

I'm trying to insert the results of a query into a table, but add a variable to the result set .  I've looked at some similar questions and I think I am representing the query variables correctly but I am getting a "global variable not defined" error.  Can you point me in the right direction?  I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that I am trying to represent a SELECT statement with a variable, but I'm not sure how the syntax should look.

```
def main():
    datadump()
    d = datetime.date.today()
    queryCurs.execute('SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY ac')
    sqlresults = queryCurs.fetchall()
    x,y,z = sqlresults
    queryCurs.execute('INSERT INTO history VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
    (d, x, y, z))
    createDb.commit
```

Thanks!

Comment: Asking questions about errors without providing traceback is pointless.

Comment: Your tuple contains `(d, a, ac, am)` but I don't see any of those (other than `d`) defined anywhere in `main()`. That seems like a good place to start.

Comment: here is the error:  
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined

Comment: The reason I didn't define it is because I wanted the results from the sqlresults assigned to d,a,ac,am.  I thought I had to do this because of the date variable I was adding to the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make two SQL queries to do this. Instead, use an INSERT query of the form [INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(...)
cursor=conn.cursor()

today = datetime.date.today()
sql='''
    INSERT INTO history
    SELECT ?, foo, bar, baz
    FROM data
    ORDER BY ac
'''
cursor.execute(sql,[today])
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The [execute](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method doesn't return a value. You would need to use [fetchone](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) or [fetchall](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) in order to get the results from the first query.

Comment: I added the fetchall method.  However, I cannot seem to figure out a way to get each tuple from the query result into the history table and adding the date to the table at the same time.  When I unpack the tuple and assign the values to x,y,z I get an error because there are 4 tuples the result from the fetch all method.  I'm probably making this way too complicated, but I just want to get the results from the first query into another table and add a date to each row.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer seems like a great way to do that. If you do need to further process the first query results in python, you would need to process the list returned by `fetchall`, i.e. in a for loop, and insert each tuple with a separate `INSERT INTO` query. You could also use `executemany` to run the insertion queries in a single command.